# Remote Debugger VS2012 - Cannot connect

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I am trying to connect to a remote debugging monitor (VS2012). Both PCs are 32bit Win7 machines. I installed the monitor using the executables that Microsoft offers on their VS2012 download page (it is the update 2 version).
I created a user on the remote machine with the same name and passwort as my local user and tried to connect. I can find the machine if I open up the monitor while VS2012 searches (but not if I initiate the search after running the debugging monitor), but when trying to connect, VS2012 gives me a "remote operation is taking longer than expected"-dialog and eventually tells me that it could not connect. I teared down the firewalls on both PCs and I am running out of ideas what to try.
I also tried to tear down the remote debugging security stuff, but the issue still persists.
Also, the Debug Monitor won't save my changes regarding user permissions. I can add a user to the list and it is still there when I reopen the dialog, but after restarting the program the changes are void. The dbug monitor is running with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting these options in Remote Debugging Monitor:  1) No Authentication (native only), 2) Allow any user to debug.  In Visual Studio, in your project's Debugging properties, select "Remote Windows Debugger" and for Connection specify "Remote with no authentication (native only)".

Comment: Thanks heaps for your effort. This didn't work, but I had the complete network settings for the remote client reconfigured and solved my problem. Sadly, I cannot narrow it down.